# Recommended button sizes on web pages

Tags: buttons, css, html, usability

What are the current usability guidelines for the size of buttons (or anything clickable) on web pages?

Comment: You can find out more information about this at below mentioned link. http://www.jaysonjc.com/programming/top-10-web-application-usability-guidelines-checklist.html I think it may be help

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that site, will take a look...

Comment: I think it depends on whether the user is accessing the web page on desktop or mobile devices to start with, and also there are similar questions already on UXSE like this: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/what-is-the-ideal-height-of-a-button-in-regular-desktop-applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are no "official" guidelines for this, so i would recommend to simply take a look at some famous sites. lets's take SO as an example - it wouldn't be such popular without:

- a good, easy to use and easy to understand ui
- the main-menue consists of only few points, so nobody gets confused
- the buttons are big, so the're easy to click, but not too big (they don't force you to move your mouse too far)
- the font-size is nice, a bit taller than the normal text to be apparent and with a good contrast to the background for easy reading without hurting your eyes
- the site itself is light and bight, the text is black on white (good contrast again, for a lot of text this is better than withe on black (in my opinion))

for more information, you could ask google for [ergonomic ui](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&expIds=17259,18167,26473,27022,27466,27740,27744&xhr=t&q=%09ergonomic+ui&cp=13&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=38fb184d66b401b2) and take a look at [this](http://ergo.human.cornell.edu/ahtutorials/interface.html) (it's not specific for websites/webapps, but good points anyway)

Answer (score 4):

Someone asked a question about the size of clickable elements and no one has mentioned Fitts's Law?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts_law

http://particletree.com/features/visualizing-fittss-law/

All other considerations aside, Fitts's Law says (aproximately) "Bigger is better, but you'll get more return from changing from small to medium than medium to big.)

Answer (score 3):

As large as possible. The larger a clickable item is, the easier it is to click on.

There are of course other factors that conflict with this, like that you want to have room for other things than just buttons...

Comment: I must disagree, if you make your buttons too large (as in frickin' huge) your site feels like Duplo. It also depends whether designing for touch or mouse - touch generally warrants bigger buttons.

Comment: @Jajub Hampl: That's not a usability concern at all, that's just a design concern. There is nothing that says that a button has to *look* as large as it actually is. A common example would be a modal popout with what looks like a close button, but clicking anywhere in the window closes the popout, so the button is actually huge and covers the entire window.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to consider is if you'll be aiming to add touch capabilities to your site. If so, that's a factor to take into consideration. On a touch device you'll want more space between buttons and, ideally, larger buttons (or at least larger target areas)

Comment: Adding to DA01's answer:
Check out this question for more answers on button sizing for touch:
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39023/what-is-the-optimum-button-size-of-touch-screen-applications And definitely check out LukeW's site, especially this article on touch target sizing:
http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1085

Answer (score 1):

IF you wish to follow Windows UX guidelines, there are indeed guidelines for the size of the button. This can be replicated to Web applications. But not sure if you would do that for web pages. 
23px is what windows UX guidelines say

Answer (score 0):

I'v just been sent a demo build which has a rounded corner checkout button that stretches the whole width of the screen. Beyond saying it kind of looks patronising I can't really back up my opinion with any data.

How big is too big for a desktop button?

Hopefully I will be able to come to a compromise with the developer using consistency of button size across the site as my argument. Fingers crossed I can make it a 3rd of the size but having it fixed on scroll so it's still always in reach.

Hard to keep up the premium look of a trust worthy brand with buttons that look like a "childs play thing"